# How to create table in RDS database on amazon web service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using AWS Amazon Web Service RDS for database. I have set up a database instance but how should I add the tables in that database instance or create any new tables in the database? Any idea how to add table?

Comment: No one knows for sure.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/rds/

Answer (score 6):

Which RDS are you using? I have been using RDS for MySQL for a long time. I create an RDS instance of MySQL and then connect to it from my laptop where I have install MySQL client program. Once I am connected, I can run all the MySQL commands just as if I ma connected to a remote database. I can create DB, Tables...blah blah..

You should provide information on the RDS instance that you are using and how your connecting to it.

Comment: I am using Mysql for RDS

Comment: then you can connect using MySQL Workbench OR MySQL CLI and can run all the MySQL commands.

Comment: i am connecting Using Mysql work bench but it gives error can not connect to my sql server,Can't connebt to mysql server.on rds.amazon.com (4) you may continue if the server is runing

Comment: do you have port 3306 access provided in your AWS security group? Are you able to Telnet to your RDS instance on port 3306? try `telnet <hostname> 3306` and post the output of this command.

Comment: @AijazAl I have the same problem when trying to connect with workbench. Even its not connecting from the local cmd too. I think the issue i understand is with the **security groups of RDS**. it wont allow access from outside. for accessing it we have **ssh to an ec2 instance and connect**. Else there need to open access to public from security group as i understand from web.

Answer (score 1):

Is your database in private or public subnet? That matters as it will affect how we can connect to it. If your RDS database is in a private subnet, then you cannot directly connect to it with a SQL client like MySQL Workbench from your PC.

I would advise you to put the database in private subnet for security concerns.

Now let's assume your database is in private subnet. What you can do is to rent a very cheap EC2 instance as a bastion instance in a public subnet. You can use SSH over TCP/IP or SSH tunneling to connect to this RDS instance even from outside your VPC as mentioned here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM7JvNMOUQM.

Here is a blog that has some details of how to do it. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cdk-rds-example

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lambda function in the VPC, use an ORM to create migrations and call the function from the command line using aws command line tool.

Answer (score 1):

1. First make sure you have an instance of ec2 running.
2. Watch this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RerDL93sBdY) on how to create security groups and add them to your database instance. This video actually guides you through the creation of a new database, but you will get it.
3. Next, follow the video to create a "database". What you have created in amazon RDS isn't really seen as a database. So you will have to use an sql statement create a database.
   Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage to ssh to your EC2 instance you can connect to your database using MySQL command line tool.

> `mysql -h [DatabaseConncetivityEndpoint] -u [usernameOfDatabaseInstance] - p [password]`

Make sure that you have installed MySQL client using   `> mysql -v`. If not you can install MySQL client inside EC2 instance:

```
> yum update
> yum install mysql
```

Then, you can flow the normal [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html) operation on the database.